# Struggling with pivoting a dataset from rows to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a dataset that has mutliple records representing different stats for the same entities.

Example:

```
DEVICE  METRIC           SCORE   WHEN
-------------------------------------------------
devA    reads_per_sec    100    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devA    writes_per_sec   50     2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devA    total_per_sec    150    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devB    reads_per_sec    200    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devB    writes_per_sec   50     2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devB    total_per_sec    250    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devC    reads_per_sec    300    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
...
```

I want to pivot everything from this table to a new table that will have this structure

```
DEVICE  READS  WRITES  TOTAL  WHEN
--------------------------------------------------
devA    100    50      150    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devB    200    50      250    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
devC    300    50      150    2011-03-01 12:00:00 AM
...
```

I have well over a dozen 'metrics' for each of thousands of devices from thousands of timestamps.

It will be far easier to query to see all metric scores for a given device on a given time if I can look at one record for a device for each sample period.

So, my question is, what is the best way to approach this and perform it? I don't mean to ask anyone to do my work for me, but this is beyond my knowledge of databases.

Comment: Can I suggest you use a different column name than `when` if at all possible? (even if it is just an example - it makes it more difficult to set up a test case)

Comment: Thanks. The column name isn't actually 'when'. I just used a meta-name here for simplicity. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will reproduce the expected result you listed:

```
  SELECT t.device,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.metric = 'reads_per_sec' THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) AS reads,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.metric = 'writes_per_sec' THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) AS writes,
         SUM(CASE WHEN t.metric = 'total_per_sec' THEN t.score ELSE 0 END) AS total,
         t.when
    FROM YOUR_TABLE t
GROUP BY t.device, t.when
ORDER BY t.device, t.when
```

If you need to deal with the various metrics, you're likely going to have to use [dynamic SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/interactive/ecpg-dynamic.html).  You'd need to get a unique list of metric values (unless you have a type code table for a foreign key reference):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.metric
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t
```

Then, concatenate the `SUM(CASE ...` for each metric before executing the query.

Comment: Thanks! Though, I do not really understand the '...THEN t.score ELSE 0 END)' What is going on there?

Comment: @NJ: See the [CASE documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) -- it's like a SWITCH statement, if you're familiar with them.

Comment: @NJ: The `... THEN t.score ELSE 0 END` is because you're summing rows into a particular column. If a particular row is invalid for a column, it must have zero effect on that column. (Excuse the pun.)

Comment: I would drop the `ELSE 0` part -- that way you will get a NULL result when the metric does not exist in a group.

Comment: @intgr: Depends on the need; NULL can cause problems in math if the value is used elsewhere.  Dropping the ELSE would also lack being explicit, which is harder to understand.